# Unable to parse date from dd-mm-yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd using moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

i am using moment.js to parse date , following is the date that i am passing as input **`16-11-2017`** and i want it to be **`2017-11-16`**

```
selected_date = moment(selected_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(selected_date);
```

I am getting invalid date when i parse, please refer to image below. [image]

Comment: From a quick RTFM is looks like you need to specify the input format (ie. pass ""DD-MM-YYYY" as the second param of `moment(…)\`.

Comment: Did you check the link in the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried giving the format of the original date

```
moment(selected_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
selected_date = moment(selected_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: The input format is given on the question's title: and that's not it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell moment the input format if it is not in a recognised format.
Try
`moment(selected_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`